# Python_How to count

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a question regarding counting in python.
I have a csv file like following:

```
GOOG,100,900.10
MSFT,50,68.99
AAPL,100,152.92
IBM,5,151.95
GOOG,150,901.25
AAPL,50,152.25
TEAM,100,36.91
NVDA,75,117.88
INTC,200,36.24
IBM,10,151.91
AAPL,700,152.15
GOOG,100,900.99
GOOG,50,900.12
```

The dataset is not clearly defined, hence I need to explain it. The first column is instrument, the second column is quantity and the last column is price. I need to read this csv file, then create columns from data which is split by , now. Then, I need to compute value by multiplying quantity with the price. Afterwards, I should count the number of trades and print the most common 5 instrument like that:

```
 Top 5 trades by number of trades:
 GOOG:   4 trade(s) total of  400 shares, $ 360,302.50
 AAPL:   3 trade(s) total of  850 shares, $ 129,409.50
  IBM:   2 trade(s) total of   15 shares, $   2,278.85
 MSFT:   1 trade(s) total of   50 shares, $   3,449.50
 TEAM:   1 trade(s) total of  100 shares, $   3,691.00
```

I have the following code which does not work, since it is not complete:

```
 from collections import defaultdict, Counter

 def analyse(filename):
   # I should write my counter here

   with open(filename) as src:
     for line in src:
       instrument, quantity, price = line.split(',')
       quantity = int(quantity)
       # I should compute value here

   # I need summarize my results here

   # This print can help me
print(f'{inst:>5}:  {count:2} trade(s) total of {quantity:4} shares, ${value:11,.2f}')

 if __name __ == '__main__':
   analyse('filename')
```

I am new in python and hence, I cannot solve this problem by myself. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check out `pd.read_csv` here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: what happens when you add the values together and hold the counts in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html%20pandas). It can do all the things you need.

Start with:

`df = pandas.read_csv(<filename>, usecols = ['ticker', 'price', quantity']))`

Use `usecols` if your csv has column names. Otherwise, set them afterwards: `df.columns = ['ticker', 'price', quantity']`.

Then you can operate on the columns like:

`df['result'] = df['price'] * df['quantity']`

Comment: @HarvIpan fixed

Answer (score 0):

First read your `csv` file using `pandas.read_csv`. Then compute your `amount` column and `pd.groupby` your values

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.csv") # optional args: names=['stock','volum', 'price'], header=None
a["amount"] = a["volum"] * a["price"]
b = a.groupby("stock").agg({"volum":sum, "amount":sum, "stock": "count"})
```

You can then `pd.sort_values` like

```
b = b.sort_values("amount", ascending=False)
```

Finally you can concatenate your text like the following:

```
b["text"] = b.index + ":   " + b["stock"].astype(str) + " trade(s) total of  " + b["volum"].astype(str) + " shares, $ " + b["amount"].astype(str)
```

Now if you `print(b["text"])` you get your desired output

```
 GOOG:   4 trade(s) total of  400 shares, $ 360,302.50
 AAPL:   3 trade(s) total of  850 shares, $ 129,409.50
  IBM:   2 trade(s) total of   15 shares, $   2,278.85
 MSFT:   1 trade(s) total of   50 shares, $   3,449.50
 TEAM:   1 trade(s) total of  100 shares, $   3,691.00
```

Comment: Does not give this answer. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Stock names are doubled. Moreover, the value in the first and second row do not seem properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)** with parameters `header` and `names` to specify that csv has no column headers and then specify the column names of your own. Then perfom multiplication and create a new column. In order to get top 5 trades you have to **[`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)** and then sort in decreasing order of count before picking top 5.

```
df = pd.read_csv("foo.csv", header=None, names=['instrument','qty', 'price'])
df['amt'] = df['qty'] * df['price']

g = df.groupby('instrument').agg({
'instrument':'count', 
'qty':'sum',
'amt':'sum'
}).rename(columns={'instrument':'count'}).sort_values(by=['count'], ascending=False).head(5)

for msg in (pd.Series(g['instrument'].map(str) + ": " + g['count'].map(str) + " trade(s) total of " + g['qty'].map(str) + " shares, $ " + round(g['amt'],2).map(str)).values):
   print(msg)
```

Output:

```
GOOG: 4 trade(s) total of 400 shares, $ 360302.5
AAPL: 3 trade(s) total of 850 shares, $ 129409.5
IBM: 2 trade(s) total of 15 shares, $ 2278.85
INTC: 1 trade(s) total of 200 shares, $ 7248.0
MSFT: 1 trade(s) total of 50 shares, $ 3449.5
```

Comment: KeyError: 'instrument'

Comment: It is not possible!! Did you follow my code perfectly?